# How do I change background color of one frame with another frame?

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, frames

I know frames are deprecated, but I need to use them for this.

I have 3 frames; upperframe, lowerrightframe, and lowerleftframe.
All frames link to another html file.
What should I put in the html file for lowerrightframe to change the background color of the lowerleftframe?

As in, the user presses a button in the lower right frame and it changes the color of the lower left frame.

Here's what I have so far (with the JS)

```
function changeBGColor (newColor)
{
     document.getElementById("lowerleftframe").style.bgColor=newColor;
}
```

and this is button.

```
<button type="button" onclick="changeBGColor('white')">Change Color</button>
```

Comment: @Nawed Khan I know how to do that in CSS, I mean say I click a button in the lower right frame it changes the color of the lower left frame.

Comment: Show us the code you already have. what you wish to do and how it is not working. What do you mean by change the color of one frame from another frame? onclick? onload?

Comment: I added the JS to the original post. I'm not sure what I should put for the button however.

Comment: @Nawed Khan Nothing happens when I try to use the button I put in the desc. of the question. What should I use?

Comment: just to be clear, you have iFrames not Frames.... these are two different things.

Comment: No I'm using frames. Not iframes.

Comment: Frames are just window... not elements. They have no property like color or background, only border, height, width and so on. You are trying to access the html page of another frame from html page of one frame. Are all html pages in the same domain?

Comment: @Nawed Khan they are all on the same domain, all in the same folder.
Makes sense with the frames. So how would I change the color then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so with lots of caveats here is a solution. 
Remember all html files should be in the same domain.
The site/files should be served on some kind of web server like localhost (at least in chrome). 
Files from different domains or from file:// will throw cross-origin restriction error for security reasons.

The top, frameset page... index.html:

```
<html>
<frameset cols="50%, 50%">
    <frame src="left.html" name="leftF"></frame>
    <frame src="right.html" name="rightF"></frame>
</frameset>
</html>
```

The html for right frame... right.html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h1>Righty</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The html and javascript for the left frame that changes the color of right frame... left.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function changeColor() {
            var f = parent.frames["rightF"];
            f.document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Lefty</h1>
    <button type="button" onclick="changeColor()">Change Color</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The actual code to change the color of another frame from one frame is:

```
var f = parent.frames["rightF"];
f.document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Where "rightF" is the name of right frame. and parent is the frameset. We are going one step up to parent then accessing frame with given name and then changing it's body.style.

Comment: Real quick, you mixed up left&right for my purpose.
Anyways, that doesn't work. It'll work if I change it to change it's own frame's color, but not others.

Comment: if you save these three files in one folder and put it in a webroot it will work. This is a simple test project that shows the concept, not using any of your file or names. You have to be more specific in what doesn't work. Look at console for any error.

Comment: I just tested with just these 3 files and the main file showed up blank.

Comment: There is nothing in the main file to not work. Here is a working example: http://nawedkhan.com/frames/

Comment: Got it working. For some reason, If I try to access the site via Chrome (by a file path on the same PC) it won't work but will in Edge and Firefox it will, but if I put it on my site it works fine on Chrome. Also, can you post that in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: It has to be served on a web server of some sort to work, at least for Chrome. Regular file:// throws cross origin restriction error. I am glad that it worked out for you. I will update this in the answer.